# Ethernet sockets on my walls

Tags: networking, ethernet

I live in a new appartement building in Korea, the walls in several rooms have ethernet sockets as
[in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjcJn.jpg).

Currently I have a modem plugged into such a socket and then a router connected to the modem to deliver wifi.

I would like to connect computers to the internet directly via ethernet in all the rooms without having a long ethernet cable to the modem. I have tried to use one of the sockets directly but I get no connection.

I also have [such a box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiPp2.jpg) full of cables in the living room, if that can help to determine the setup of the flat.

Comment: "I have tried to use one of the sockets directly but I get no connection." - You have to connect the other end of the socket to something, it's not currently connected to anything, more than likely.  You would typically connect the sockets to a single switch, connect a modem to the switch, thus giving all ports access to the internet.  However, everyone is different, some people just connect the sockets to a intranet.

Comment: The cables in the picture look like DSL connections.  You should ask the Landlord what you have, how to connect, and if more that one outlet is active.

Comment: A Cat-5e socket doesn't necessarily mean it's Ethernet. If there's a modem it must be some kind of DSL. You'll need to ask your landlord about the cabling.